# Handling subclasses of HttpServerErrorException using @Retryable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-batch

I am using spring batch.Sometimes, I get `502` Http response. Below is the exception message I get:

```
Error finding details for ids [123, 456 ] due to I/O error on POST request for \""http://localhost:18080/my/api/path/findByIds\"": localhost:18080 failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:18080 failed to respond "",""level"":""err"",""thread"":""taskExecutor-1"",""logClass"":""c.t.k.e.r.myRepository"",""logMethod"":""findPersonByIds"",
```

Whatever the error from server side is wrapped up in `HttpServerErrorException` . I had look at this exception class . `BadGateway` is a subclass of `HttpServerErrorException`. I have two different use cases(in separate projects I am working on).

a)I have to retry only when a `BadGateway` exception occurs.

b)Whenever `BadGateway` and the  exception body contains `NoHttpResponseException` , I need to retry(use case 2 in a different project)

I have tried something like this but has not worked .

```
@Retryable(value = NoHttpResponseException.class)
myMethod()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a component (or bean) that will allow you to perform the custom logic on the root exception and reference it in the @Retryable annotation. Any exceptions thrown will call the shouldRetry() method

```
@Component
public class ExceptionChecker {

    public boolean shouldRetry(Throwable t) {
        // perform logic on exception to check if retry is required
        return true;
    }
}

// Use the name of the component (exceptionChecker in this case) in the annotation
// and pass the exception to the shouldRetry method

@Retryable(exceptionExpression = "@exceptionChecker.shouldRetry(#root)")
public String retryableMethod(String name) {
```